# GROUP BY with 2 table

Tags: sql, sqlbase

I can make group by when it is onlyTBRACCD table, when I add the SPRIDEN it doesn't accept for this code?

```
  SELECT  -- tbraccd_pidm,     
             spriden_pidm,
             spriden_first_name
        CASE
            WHEN   SUM (NVL (tbraccd_bae, 0))  < 50
             THEN
                'Y'
             ELSE
             'N'
           END    paid         
     FROM tbraccd, spriden
     WHERE tbraccd_term_code = '201950'
       and SPRIDEN_PIDM=tbraccd_pidm
     GROUP BY tbraccd_pidm, tbraccd_term_code;
```

Comment: Change your group by to reflect your `SELECT`: `GROUP BY spriden_pidm,             spriden_first_name`

Comment: Use modern join syntax. It makes your life (and ours) way easier.

Answer (score 0):

try like below , add `spriden_first_name`, `spriden_pidm` column also in group by and use modern join not coma separated join

```
   SELECT  -- tbraccd_pidm,     
                 spriden_pidm,
                 spriden_first_name
            CASE
                WHEN   SUM (NVL (tbraccd_bae, 0))  < 50
                 THEN
                    'Y'
                 ELSE
                 'N'
               END    paid         
         FROM tbraccd join  spriden  on SPRIDEN_PIDM=tbraccd_pidm
         WHERE tbraccd_term_code = '201950'          
         GROUP BY spriden_pidm, tbraccd_term_code,spriden_first_name;
```